# Date format coming in weird way in CSV file using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date, csv

I have a codeigniter function to create a CSV file for the user data from a DB.

My function is this:-

```
function user_CSV()
{
    $filename = 'CSV_User_Report.csv';      
    $this->load->dbutil();      
    $this->load->helper('file');        
    $this->load->helper('download');        
    $delimiter = ",";        
    $newline = "\r\n";  
    $queryUser = "SELECT user_name AS Name, 
                    user_username AS Username, 
                    user_mobile AS Mobile, 
                    DATE_FORMAT( user_added_date, '%d-%m-%Y' ) AS `Joining Date`,
                    DATE_FORMAT( user_last_activity, '%d-%m-%Y' ) AS `Last Acitivity`
                FROM tbl_user"; 
    $dataResult = $this->db->query($queryUser);
    if($dataResult->num_rows()>0)       
    {   
        $data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($dataResult, $delimiter, $newline);      
    }   
    if(force_download($filename, $data))        
    {           
        redirect('admin/user');     
    }
}
```

Now, this one is creating the CSV file. But there is a severe issue. To illustrate that, I am sharing the screenshot of the CSV.
[image]

As you can see, some of the Joining Date is coming in dd/m/YYYY format, and some dd-mm-YYYY format.

But, when I am trying to see the query in phpmyadmin, I am getting the result like this:-
[image]

Why is such inconsistency of display of date format in CSV data?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: any possibility that it's just an Excel display issue? what happens if you format those cells to display the date properly, also how do the dates look like in the csv if you open the file in a text editor, notepad or notepad++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My educated guess, without really looking at your code, is that your Spreadsheet software is assuming that dates come in American format (MM-DD-YYYY) so it's doing two things:

- If day is 12 or less it misreads the date and swaps day and month
- If day is greater than 13 it think it isn't a valid date and displays as string

CSV is a very loose format and does not provide any standard way to format dates. Yet I suggest something like YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: yes, you are right. It was due to the Amercian format the softwares are following. The solution which I made is to fetch the date in `'%d-%M-%Y'` format. This solved the problem.